# Learning the Navajo Language

Tags: self-learning

My colleague is really interested in the Navajo and their language. He is tying to learn the language for some time now and has done all the courses he could find on the internet, only those were only beginners courses.

Does anyone happen to have any advice on how to move on from there? The beginners courses only cover some basic words, numbers and sentences. He would like to know how the grammar works and of course new words and sentences.

Any advice/tips on how to become more intermediate/advanced in using the Navajo language would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to LL.SE and interesting first question. Could you add more detail about what beginner courses your friend has already taken?

Comment: Has he completed the Duolingo course in Navajo?

Comment: Has he looked at Navajo language leaning books on Amazon? For example, “Breakthrough Navajo” by Alan Wilson